# Adal library with reverse proxy (asp webservice)

Tags: azure, authentication, reverse-proxy, adfs, adal

I am working on an app for some company, but I have some problems with the security measures in combination with the [Azure ADAL library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet).

For security reasons they setup a ADFS authentication server with the guys of microsoft. So that my webservice can only be **accessed by a token given by the authentication server.**

I use the adal library to get this authentication token and **inside the network I have no problems with accessing the webservice.**

For outside the network, I need to go through the proxy, this using a reverse proxy. For authentication on the reverse proxy you also need to authenticate to the ADFS authentication server.

**Here is an image to explain it a little bit better :)**

[image: Drawing of the authentication]
**For the inside phone**

1. Send authentication request to the adfs authentication server.
2. Get back a authorization token.
3. Send a request for data to the webservice with the authentication token

**For the outside phone**

1. Send authentication request to the internal adfs authentication server. This needs to pass through the reverse proxy.
2. The reverse proxy sees that you are not authenticated and will first authenticate with the external adfs authentication server, before he will let you pass through.
3. This authentication will add a cookie inside the httpclient so that it knows the request is already authenticated.
4. Now it will request the authentication token, and because it has the cookie inside the request, it will not need to authentication anymore.
5. It will return the token to the phone.
6. I am now trying to request some data from the webservice, with the token in the request. But **inside the [Azure ADAL library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) I cannot get access to the cookie** to add this to the request to pass me through the Reverse Proxy. So the reverse proxy will block me an instead of a data response **I will get the login page from the reverse proxy back as an html string.**

**So the problem that I am trying to address is that I cannot get access to the cookie inside the [Azure ADAL library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet), or is there any other fix I didn't seeing.**

Comment: When you say "send authentication request" in step 1, how are you doing this? Are you using ADAL? Or are you crafting your own authentication request? 

The ADAL library is used to get tokens. But it seems that in step 5, you have already gotten the token. So I am confused about what you are using ADAL to do.  Could you please also post some code? That would help us understand.